# Adding Data on DevExpress GridView

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am a new to DevExpress and to programming as well. My question is how to add data to a gridcontrol which isn't connected to any datasource. I might also paste a data since adding data one at a time would be time consuming.

Regards,
Kim

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to assign datasource at design-time, you can create a run-time data source programmatically:

**Using DataTable:**

```
DataTable runtimeSource = new DataTable();
DataColumn columnID = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
DataColumn columnName = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
DataColumn columnAge = new DataColumn("Age", typeof(string));

runtimeSource.Columns.Add(columnID);
runtimeSource.Columns.Add(columnName);
runtimeSource.Columns.Add(columnAge);

gridControl.DataSource = runtimeSource;
gridControl.PopulateColumns();
```

For adding rows, call the below sample method:

```
private void AddRow(int id, string name, string age)
{
    var runtimeSource = gridControl.DataSource as DataTable;

    DataRow dRow = runtimeSource.NewRow();
    dRow.ItemArray = new object[] { id, name, age };

    runtimeSource.Rows.Add(dRow);

    gridControl.RefreshDataSource();
}
```

To Paste data, just call `AddRow` method in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for helping me and writing some codes. I really appreciate it. What i'm looking for is to add data directly on the gridcontrol just like an excel document.

Answer (score 1):

GridControl always works with its data source. It can't work without any data source. For your task, I suggest you use [Spreadsheet](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument12063). It's an Excel counterpart.